# PHP: Error con la función mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, html, login

Tengo este código. Y no puedo encontrar el error del `php`.

Mi código es el siguiente:

`HTML`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
         <title>registro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="correo" required>
        <input type="password" name="con" placeholder="contraseña" required>
        <input type="submit" value="loggear">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

`PHP`

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pw2="";
    $db="programate";
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $pw=$_POST["con"];
    $con=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw2);
    $sel=mysql_query("SELECT    EMAIL,PW FROM registro WHERE EMAIL='$email'",$con);
    $sesion=mysql_fetch_array($sel);
    if ($pw == $sesion["PW"]) {
    $_SESSION["name"] =$email;
    echo "iniciado secion";
    }else{
    echo "verifique si no ubo un error al escribir los datos"; 
    }
    ?>
```

Me dice que tengo un error en

> $sesion=mysql_fetch_array($sel); linea 11

Y no puedo hallarla, ¿qué creen ustedes? No sé cuál es el error.

Comment: Por favor añade el mensaje de error exacto que obtienes

Answer (score 0):

La función `mysql_fetch_array`fue declarada como obsoleta en la versión PHP 5.5.0  y luego  eliminada en la versión 7.0.

Debe ser reemplazada por `mysqli_fetch_array()` o mejor aun por `PDOStatement::fetch()`

> Advertencia Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y
> eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones
> MySQLi o PDO_MySQL. Véase también la guía MySQL: elegir una API y sus
> P+F relacionadas para más información. Alternatives to this function
> include:
>
> - mysqli_fetch_array()
> - PDOStatement::fetch()

**Fuente:** https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

NOTA: En esta línea te falto conectar con la base:

```
$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pw2);
```

Debería ser así

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw2, $db);
```

porque no sabe de donde es esa tabla si no hay base.

Este es un ejemplo: `$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");`

Mirá: [mysqli_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php), ya que **mysql_connect** fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0